# Prometheus metrics not constant

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Prometheus metrics are different in different iterations even though application, load testing, hardware configurations are same in all cases. Kindly, anyone let me know the reason for this.

Edited - Added additional information based on questions posted below

I have created a container with simple "Hello World" web application in node.js and load testing it with 1000 users. Container is deployed in Digital Ocean cloud environment and container metrics are gathered using Prometheus. I'm capturing the maximum CPU and maximum memory utilization.

For every iteration(where I load test with 1000 users) I run, I'm getting different maximum CPU and  Memory utilization metrics.

My assumption is, if the test parameters and  hardware configurations remains same, the maximum utilization metrics also should remain same.

Question - why I'm getting different metrics?

Comment: I guess you have multiple instances of Prometheus running. If so, take a look for Thanos.

Comment: Please explain what metrics are you collecting and how these metrics are being collected. If your application has 3 replicas and all of them exporting metrics. If you use a Service to pull the metrics, then on each pull the request may load balance into one of these replicas resulting different metrics on different iterations.

Comment: @manuel -  It is a single instance of Prometheus

Comment: @Emruz Hussain - I have added more information to the question above